# Python jsonschema not flagging date-time errors

Tags: python, json, validation, jsonschema

I'm having some trouble understanding how to validate data using `jsonschema`, which came to light when I started trying to validate date-time values.

The following code should raise a `ValidationError` exception, but it doesn't. It's the shortest example I've been able to come up with.

```
def val(data, schema):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(data, schema)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
        return e.args[0]

result = val('2008-09-0X22:47:31-07:00', {'format': 'date-time'})
print(result)
```

The result is `None` for any string value, although

```
val(42, {'type': 'string', 'format': 'date-time'})
```

raises the exception with "42 is not of type 'string'". This does *not* happen if I omit the `'type'` schema item, and the validator again returns `None`.

It seems to me I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how to use the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As stated in the jsonschema documentation:](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/#validating-formats)

> By default, no validation [of `format`] is enforced, but optionally, validation can be enabled by hooking in a format-checking object into an `IValidator`.

It then shows an example of how to do that:

```
validate(
    "-12", {"format" : "hostname"}, format_checker=FormatChecker(),
)
```

So all you need to do is:

```
jsonschema.validate('2008-09-0X22:47:31-07:00', {'format': 'date-time'}, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
```

Do note that, as stated at the bottom of the page, the `date-time` format is only enforced if you also have the `strict-rfc3339` package installed.

Comment: Thanks. `strict-rfc3339` _is_ installed. I'm actually trying to replace the validation done by the `connexion` package, so it might be quite a big job.

Comment: `from jsonschema import validate, FormatChecker       
validate({"2001-02"},  {"type": "string", "format": "date"}, format_checker=FormatChecker()) # throws validation error as expected        
validate({"dob": "2001-02"}, {"dob": {"type": "string", "format": "date"}}, format_checker=FormatChecker()) # Doesnt throw error which is wrong`
Can someone help ? am i missing something ?